# Debug file used by another process

Tags: c#, debugging

Using Visual Studio 2010 and im getting "File is used by another process" almost randomly when trying to read a file. Im reading about 10 xml files into memory with the same procedure

The code that breaks is

```
private static TextReader CreateTextReader(IsolatedStorageFile isolatedStorageFolder, string path)
        {
            TextReader textReader = null;

            if (isolatedStorageFolder == null)
                textReader = new StreamReader(path);
            else
                textReader = new StreamReader(new IsolatedStorageFileStream(path, FileMode.Open, isolatedStorageFolder));

            return textReader;
        }
```

The code breaks 10 percent of the time on

```
 textReader = new StreamReader(path);
```

I personally think its some kind of garbage collection problem, anyone has any tips on how to debug this kind of problem.

Comment: do you dispose your `StreamReader`?

Comment: Yes , the textreader is in a using statement. And i have also done close on textreader, even if i should not have to.

Comment: Sometimes Antivirus Programs or Windows Indexing keeps a handle open on files. Try turning both of those off to see if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to call .Dispose or .Close on all steam reader operations that could lock the file. That might be your problem as that code works for me as a flat program.

Answer (score 1):

You need to dispose of the `TextReader`. Use the `using` statement like

```
using (TextReader r = CreateTextReader(...))
{
}
```

Otherwise the file will remain open when you close your application.

**EDIT**
You're saying in your comments to the question that you're actually already using `using` - could it be that the file you're trying to read is actually opened by another application? Sometimes antivir solutions lock files while scanning them or stuff like that - will it work after a short while or do you have to reboot or something like that?